# Unable to update Symfony version

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm having dificulties in upgrading the Symfony version to 4.4.*. I'm getting this error message.

`Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.3
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0-RC1
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0-BETA2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v4.4.0-BETA1
    - don't install symfony/http-client v5.0.7|don't install symfony/symfony 4.4.x-dev
    - don't install symfony/symfony 4.4.x-dev|remove symfony/http-client v5.0.7
    - don't install symfony/symfony 4.4.x-dev|don't install symfony/http-client v5.0.7
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 4.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[4.4.x-dev, v4.4.0, v4.4.0-BETA1, v4.4.0-BETA2, v4.4.0-RC1, v4.4.1, v4.4.2, v4.4.3, v4.4.4, v4.4.5, v4.4.6, v4.4.7].
    - Installation request for symfony/http-client (locked at v5.0.7, required as ^5.0) -> satisfiable by symfony/http-client[v5.0.7].`

I checked some questions on StackOverflow that help me a little, but I'm start to think that every error in this composer script is a different error.

This is part of my composer.json

`"php": "~7.3.0",
    "resquebundle/resque": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "1.1.1",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.7",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "^1.1",
    "league/fractal": "0.12.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "4.4.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/http-client": "^5.0"`
Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Create a fresh 4.4 project then add your third party bundles letting composer pick whatever version is most suitable.  That will give you a working composer.json file which you can use as a starting point.  Or, if a third party bundle does not install cleanly then it will narrow down the issue.

Comment: Try to change all `symfony/*` (except `assetic-bundle`, this one is deprecated a long time) to `"symfony/*": "4.4.*"` and then `composer update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`symfony/symfony` is the main repository for all Symfony components. Have a look at   the "replaces" section at https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/symfony to see which exact components are covered.

In your special case, an installation of `symfony/symfony` in v4.4.* replaces an installation of `symfony/http-client` in the exact same version. Additionally, your configuration lists a strict requirement of `symfony/http-client` in v5.0 through the last line of the `composer.json`. As one package can not be installed in two different versions at the same time, this can not be resolved automatically.

You have two possibilities: either install `symfony/symfony` in v5.0 (which might cause new problems with other packages), or install `symfony/http-client` in v4.4. In both cases, you should afterwards either split up the requirement of `symfony/symfony` into the set of really required components; or remove `symfony/http-client`. Having all components in the list of requirements **and** listing one component seperately does not make sense

Comment: Thanks mate, got it. I think it will not be simple to go through, but I have to dive in and your explanation helped me a lot.